# How can i set color of the bullet depending on the data passed from the external array of values?

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4

i have two types of data in one graph - the normal range (bars) and the value (line wiht bullets). if the value is more or less then the range - the color of bullet must be red, meaning that the value is not normal... How is it possible to pass there in the graph the precalculated color or calculate it by means of adapter function or any other working way?
[image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlsBf.png)

```
let data = [
  {
      code: "07090",    
      name: "Sodium",    
      result: 150,
      unit: "mmol/L",
      refMin: 137,
      refMax: 149,
      date: "2019-10-04"
  },
  {
      code: "07090",    
      name: "Sodium",    
      result: 139,
      unit: "mmol/L",
      refMin: 135,
      refMax: 147,
      date: "2019-10-06"
  },
  {
      code: "07090",    
      name: "Sodium",    
      result: 130,
      unit: "mmol/L",
      refMin: 135,
      refMax: 147,
      date: "2019-10-07"
  },
  {
      code: "07090",    
      name: "Sodium",    
      result: 140,
      unit: "mmol/L",
      refMin: 135,
      refMax: 147,
      date: "2019-11-07"
  },
  {
      code: "07090",    
      name: "Sodium",    
      result: 147,
      unit: "mmol/L",
      refMin: 135,
      refMax: 147,
      date: "2019-11-08"
  },
  {
      code: "07090",    
      name: "Sodium",    
      result: 147,
      unit: "mmol/L",
      refMin: 134,
      refMax: 146,
      date: "2019-11-10"
  },
  {
      code: "07090",    
      name: "Sodium",    
      result: 147,
      unit: "mmol/L",
      refMin: 134,
      refMax: 146,
      date: "2020-11-10"
  },
  {
      code: "07090",    
      name: "Sodium",    
      result: 147,
      unit: "mmol/L",
      refMin: 134,
      refMax: 146,
      date: "2020-11-11"
  }

];

let cols = [];
let lines = [];
let chartData = [];

for(let { result, refMin, refMax, date } of data) {
  let markerColor = "#fff"; // !!!! the color is predefined here 
  if (result > refMax || result < refMin) {
    markerColor = "#f00";
  }

  chartData.push({
    date: new Date(date),
    result: result,
    colMin: refMin,
    colMax: refMax,
    markerColor
  });
}

am4core.ready(function() {

// Themes begin
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
// Themes end

// Create chart instance
var chart = am4core.create("chartContainer", am4charts.XYChart);
chart.responsive.enabled = true;

// Add data
chart.data = chartData;

// Create axes
var dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
dateAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 50;

var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

var seriesCols = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
seriesCols.dataFields.dateX  = "date";
seriesCols.dataFields.valueY  = "colMax";
seriesCols.dataFields.openValueY = "colMin";
seriesCols.fill = am4core.color("#ccc");
seriesCols.strokeWidth = 0;
seriesCols.name = "Range";
seriesCols.tooltipText = "{colMin} - {colMax}";
seriesCols.tooltip.pointerOrientation = "horizontal";
seriesCols.tooltip.background.cornerRadius = 0;
seriesCols.tooltip.background.fillOpacity = 0.5;
seriesCols.tooltip.label.padding(10,10,7,10);

// Create series
var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
let circleBullet = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
circleBullet.circle.stroke = "#fff";
circleBullet.circle.fillOpacity = ".7";
circleBullet.circle.strokeWidth = 1;

series.dataFields.valueY = "result";
series.dataFields.dateX = "date";
series.dataFields.dummyData = "date";
series.strokeWidth = 2;
series.minBulletDistance = 30;
series.tooltipText = "{valueY}";
series.tooltip.pointerOrientation = "vertical";
series.tooltip.background.cornerRadius = 20;
series.tooltip.background.fillOpacity = 0.5;
series.tooltip.label.padding(12,12,12,12);
series.dummyData = { color: "markerColor" };

series.adapter.add("fill", function(fill, lalal) {
  return fill;
});

// Add scrollbar
chart.scrollbarX = new am4charts.XYChartScrollbar();
chart.scrollbarX.series.push(series);

// Add cursor
chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
chart.cursor.xAxis = dateAxis;
chart.cursor.snapToSeries = series;

});
```

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED:

```
circleBullet.propertyFields.fill = "bulletColor";
```